# Why do I get the error Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type ...?

Tags: angular, typescript, bryntum-scheduler

I have created a new angular application.

In the app.component.html I have

```
<bryntum-scheduler
    #scheduler
    [resources] = "resources"
    [events] = "events"
    [columns] = "schedulerConfig.columns"
    [startDate] = "schedulerConfig.startDate!"
    [endDate] = "schedulerConfig.endDate!"
></bryntum-scheduler>
```

the app.component.ts looks like

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BryntumSchedulerComponent } from '@bryntum/scheduler-angular';
import { schedulerConfig } from './app.config';

@Component({
    selector    : 'app-root',
    templateUrl : './app.component.html',
    styleUrls   : ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    resources = [
        { id : 1, name : 'Dan Stevenson' },
        { id : 2, name : 'Talisha Babin' }
    ];

    events = [
        { resourceId : 1, startDate : '2022-01-01', endDate : '2022-01-10' },
        { resourceId : 2, startDate : '2022-01-02', endDate : '2022-01-09' }
    ];

    schedulerConfig = schedulerConfig;

    @ViewChild('scheduler') schedulerComponent!: BryntumSchedulerComponent;
}
```

and this is the app.config.ts (in the same folder as app.component.ts):

```
import { SchedulerConfig } from '@bryntum/scheduler';

export const schedulerConfig: Partial<SchedulerConfig> = {
    columns : [
        { text : 'Name', field : 'name', width : 160 }
    ],
    startDate : new Date(2022, 10, 17),
    endDate   : new Date(2022, 10, 23)
};
```

When I try to compile my app, I get the error

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'object | object[] |
> ColumnStore | Partial |
> Partial[]'.
>
> 5     [columns] = "schedulerConfig.columns"

I do not seen the cause of this error. Can someone help me?

Comment: What's the @Input() definition of columns?

Comment: its a 3rd-party component. I see in the exported class: columns: ColumnStore | object[] | object | Partial<ColumnStoreConfig> | Partial<ColumnStoreConfig>[];

Comment: Try schedulerConfig?.columns in your template

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official [docs](https://www.bryntum.com/docs/scheduler/api/Grid/data/ColumnStore), `ColumnStore` has many properties, some of them you have defined (text, field, width), so you could "soft" cast `columns` to `ColumnStore` when passing to this component like so:

```html
<bryntum-scheduler
    #scheduler
    [resources] = "resources"
    [events] = "events"
    [columns] = "schedulerConfig.columns as ColumnStore" <!--here-->
    [startDate] = "schedulerConfig.startDate!"
    [endDate] = "schedulerConfig.endDate!"
></bryntum-scheduler>
```